# How to use noImplicitOverride flag from TS4.3 with React class components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've updated TS to 4.3 and tried to add flag noImplicitOverride to my tsconfig.json.

I've got a lot of issues related to overriding inside my React class components ie. render()

Is it some approach to use this flag with React?

Comment: +1 to this question. How can we use `noImplicitOverride` but exclude some method such as `render` without having to add the override keyword to all of the occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, add the `override` keyword before any methods that override the method from the base class:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  override render() {
    return <p>Hello, world!</p>
  }
}
```

Note that this is not React-specific and applies in general to all classes that extend another class.

See the [reference on `noImplicitOverride`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitOverride) for more information.

---

Alternatively, if you don’t to add `override` before each `render()`, you could use [functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) instead with [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).